# Template function with a vector<A<X>>::iterator parameter fails template argument deduction

Tags: c++, templates, mingw, c++14, template-argument-deduction

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <unsigned X> class A{};

template <unsigned X> void testfunc(std::vector<A<X>> f) { std::cout << "Hello one" << std::endl;}
template <unsigned X> void testfunctwo(typename std::vector<A<X>>::iterator f) { std::cout << "Hello two" << std::endl;}


int main(){

    std::vector<A<2>> f;
    f.push_back(A<2>());

    testfunc(f);
    testfunctwo<2>(f.begin());
    testfunctwo(f.begin());


}
```

You can see in the first case the compiler can deduce the value of `X` as expected. In the second case the function takes a vector iterator an explicit template parameter is used, the function of course runs normally. In the third case there is template argument deduction failure:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'testfunctwo(std::vector<A<2u> >::iterator)'|
note: candidate: template<unsigned int X> void testfunctwo(typename std::vector<A<X> >::iterator)|
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
note:   couldn't deduce template parameter 'X'|
```

The compiler notes that the template function `testfunctwo` is a candidate but cannot deduce the template parameter `X`. The only difference between it and `testfunc` is that it takes an iterator instead. How come the introduction of a typename causes template argument deduction to fail? `f.begin()` has type `std::vector<A<2>>::iterator`, personally looking at it, it should be very clear what the template parameter should be.

Compiler is MinGW g++ 6.1.0

Comment: Interesting... no need of `class A` to show this; you can use `std::array` with `template <std::size_t S> void testA0 (std::array<int, S> const &) { }` and `template <std::size_t S> void testA1 (typename std::array<int, S>::iterator const &) { }`

Comment: This is a non-deduced context: it's not going to go through all possible `vector<A<X>>` and check if they have an `iterator` member matching your argument.  This is not even possible in general, e.g. imagine if `vector::iterator` is implemented as a raw pointer